# Filter on nested list using Java 8 Stream API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm not able to convert below snippet in Java 8 stream format.

```
List<String> titles = Arrays.asList("First Name", "Last Name");

for (FirstClass first : firstClassList) {
    for (SecondClass second : first.getSecondClassList()) {
        for (ThirdClass third : second.getThirdClassList()) {                   

            if(!titles.contains(third.getField())) {
                second.getThirdClassList().remove(third);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I'm comparing third level nested list object against the input list of fields. If fields are not matching then I'm removing them from original list. 
How can I achieve this using Java 8 syntax.

Edit: I want List of FirstClass to be returned.

Comment: [Stream#flatMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) and [Stream#filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) methods could help for this scenario

Comment: To use streams instead of the for loops you want to flatten the data-structure, i.e. something like `firstClassList.stream().flatMap(FirstClass::getSecondClassList()` and similar for the second level.

Comment: This code doesn't work, it throws ConcurrentModificationException

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think streams win you anything in this case.  All you do is iterate over the nested lists and either the enhanced for loop or [`forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) is more straightforward.

The improvements can come from using [`removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) to modify the list and, possibly, from moving the rejection logic out of the loop:

```
Predicate<ThirdClass> reject = third -> !titles.contains(third.getField());

firstClassList.forEeach(first ->
    first.getSecondClassList().forEach(second ->
        second.getThirdClassList().removeIf(reject)
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

First you can use [`Stream.map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) and [`Stream.flatMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) to get a `Stream` containing a `List` of `ThirdClass`. To remove the items matching the condition you could use [`Collection.removeIf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-), which removes all items from a collection matching the given condition:

```
firstClassList.stream()                         // Stream<FirstClass>
        .map(FirstClass::getSecondClassList)    // Stream<List<SecondClass>>
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)            // Stream<SecondClass>
        .map(SecondClass::getThirdClassList)    // Stream<List<ThirdClass>>
        .forEach(thirdList -> thirdList.removeIf(third -> !titles.contains(third.getField())));
```

This modifies the original List, just like you did in your example. You then can use `firstClassList` as result for further processing.

Beside that I would recommend using a [`Set<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) instead of a `List<String>` for your titles, because it has a time complexity of *O(1)* instead of *O(n)*:

```
Set<String> titles = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("First Name", "Last Name"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Get a stream of `SecondClass` objects by flattening the `firstClassList` and for each `SecondClass` get the filtered list of `ThirdClass` objects and set it back in the `SecondClass`

```
List<String> titles = Arrays.asList("First Name", "Last Name");

firstClassList
    .stream()
    .flatMap(firstClass -> firstClass.getSecondClassList().stream())
    .forEach(secondClass -> {
             List<ThirdClass> filteredThirdClasses = secondClass.getThirdClassList()
                        .stream()
                        .filter(thirdClass -> titles.contains(thirdClass.getField()))
                        .collect(toList());

             secondClass.setThirdClassList(filteredThirdClasses);
         }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the three levels in your data-structure are collections then a solution could be:

1. flatten the structure to a stream of the leaf level
2. filter by the required titles

```
final List<ThirdClassList> results = firstClassList
    .stream()
    .flatMap(FirstClassList::getSecondClassList)
    .flatMap(FirstClassList::getThirdClassList)
    .filter(third -> !titles.contains(third))
    .collect(toList());
```

This will give you the leaf level objects to be removed, though this is only half the solution of course, you still want to remove them.

If you are the author of the list classes then perhaps you could have a reference from each third level to its 'parent' second level so removing is then a relatively simple second step:

```
results.forEach(third -> third.parent().remove(this));
```

where `third.parent()` returns the second level object.

Comment: For performance, you could change the intermediate `List` to `Stream#iterator()` and `Iterator#remove()` - as long as the final `Stream` supports element removal.

Comment: stridecolossus, thanks for your response. But I need FirstClass List instead of leaf.